# How could a path be homotopic to a point

Tags: general-topology, complex-analysis

I have been following Serge Lang's Intoduction to Complex Analysis at a Graduate Level and I met this theorem. I want to ask what does it mean for a function to be homotopic to a point? I am only familiar with paths being homotopic to each other but not to a point. Here is the extract

[image]

If anybody could shine some light onto this I will really appreciate it.

Comment: "Point" here means "constant path at a point".

Comment: Hi @BenSteffan, by "constant path at a point" do you mean a path that consists of one point?

Comment: Yes, MathsWizard, that's precisely what it means. This is true when the set $U$ is simply connected.

Comment: Hi @TedShifrin, thank you for the comment. Could you clarify what you are referring to as being true for U simply connected?

Comment: In a simply connected region, every closed path is homotopic to a constant path. Most students encounter this notion, at least intuitively, in multivariable calculus.

Comment: @TedShifrin I just realised the notion of simply connected is literary on the next page ... Thank you very much for taking the time for explaining this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A **path homotopy** $f\to g$ is a homotopy $H=H(x,t)$ such that $H(x,0)=f(x)$ and $H(x,1)=g(x).$ A path $f$ is **homotopic to a point** $c$ if it is path homotopic to the constant path $c(x)=c$ for each $x.$

Consider this example: let $f(x)=(\sin x,\cos x)$ be the path which traces out the unit circle in $\mathbb R^2$. Then the path homotopy $H(x,t)= tf(x)$ has $H(x,1)=f(x)$ and $H(x,0)=0$ for each $x.$ It follows that $f$ is homotopic to the point $0$ since it is homotopic to the constant path at $0.$

Comment: hello mate, shouldnt 0 be a point in R2 since H is a map (x,t) to R2? But it seems 0 is a point in R not R2

Comment: @qubitz By $0$ here I mean $(0,0).$